# Edit and Continue: "Changes are not allowed when..."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, edit-and-continue

Even if I create a clean WinForms project, Edit and Continue doesn't work and gives me the error:

> Changes are not allowed when the debugger has been attached to an already running process or the code being debugged was optimized at build or run time.

1. Edit and Continue option is checked in Tools → Options → Debugging.
2. Optimization is not enabled.
3. Seems like there is no any managed profiler set up.
4. I am running in Debug mode
5. I am running on x64 CPU and Windows XP 32-bit, but setting platform target to x86 rather than AnyCpu doesn't help.
6. Repairing Visual Studio installation doesn't help.

I also found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164927(VS.80).aspx) on MSDN website:

> **Unsupported Scenarios**
>
> Edit and Continue is not available in the following debugging scenarios:
>
> - Debugging on Windows 98.
> - Mixed-mode (native/managed) debugging.
> - SQL debugging.
> - Debugging a Dr. Watson dump.
> - Editing code after an unhandled exception, when the "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" option is not selected.
> - Debugging an embedded runtime application.
> - Debugging an application with Attach to rather than running the application with Start from the Debug menu.
> - Debugging optimized code.
> - Debugging managed code when the target is a 64-bit application. If you want to use Edit and Continue, you must set the target to x86. (Project Properties, Compile tab, Advanced Compiler setting.).
> - Debugging an old version of your code after a new version failed to build due to build errors.

But I can answer "No" to every item in this list.

It worked before, but several days ago it stopped working, and I don't know what could be the reason.

Comment: Are you running in Release mode? Are you running on X64?

Comment: Is the method you are trying to E&C really short? perhaps it got inlined (though i think inlining does not happen on debug)

Comment: It doesn't work on any methods, either very short or very long.

Comment: Did you try a repair installation yet?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it with no luck :(

Comment: Isn't that a great error message? I used to work on that team, so I guess I should apologize.

Comment: I guess I should add that E&C is a pretty complex feature. The debugger's test matrix is enormous, and getting E&C to work in every combination would be extremely hard. But it's a really important feature, too, so we took on a lot of limitations to make sure it would ship.  Within the deliberate constraints we placed on it, it's one of the highest-quality features we shipped.

Comment: If it helps, I found turning OFF "Enable Edit and Continue" allowed it to work - VS 2017, .Net Web Application, Any CPU, Debug mode.

Comment: I can confirm in VS2017 that Edit &Continue works in managed 64bit applications, even if officially unsupported.

Comment: I submitted a request to Microsoft about providing reasons in the error message. Please vote it up if you think it should get some priority: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Hot-ReloadEdit-and-Continue-should-prov/10297825

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I finally got to solve the problem: **UNINSTALL Gallio**

Gallio seems to have quite some many rough edges and it's better to not use MbUnit 3.0 but use the MbUnit 2.0 framework but use the gallio runner, that you are running without installing from the installer (which also installed a visual studio plugin).

Incidentally, I had the issue even after "disabling" he Gallio plugin. Only the uninstall solved the problem.

**PS. Edited by nightcoder:**
In my case **disabling TypeMock Isolator** (mocking framework) finally **helped**! Edit & Continue now works!!!

Here is the answer from TypeMock support:

> After looking further into the edit
>   and continue issue, and conversing
>   about it with Microsoft, we reached
>   the conclusion it cannot be resolved
>   for Isolator. Isolator implements a
>   CLR profiler, and according to our
>   research, once a CLR profiler is
>   enabled and attached, edit and
>   continue is automatically disabled.
>   I'm sorry to say this is no longer
>   considered a bug, but rather a
>   limitation of Isolator.

Answer (score 87):

#### Other Applicable Solutions:

**Below is an incomplete, *unordered* list of possible solutions to try if you* are trying to fix Edit & Continue quickly.**

- Make sure you are in *Debug Mode*
- Make sure you're not launching a mixed mode process
- Try to set the CPU target to *x86* rather than *AnyCPU* (on x64 machines)
- Uncheck the *Optimize Code* checkbox for *Debug Mode* in *Project Properties->Debug*
- Uncheck the *Optimize Code* checkbox in *Project Properties->Build*
- Uncheck *Enable Optimizations* in *Advanced Compiler Settings*
- (ASP.NET) Check [nightcoder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010213/edit-and-continue-changes-are-not-allowed-when-the-debugger-has-been-attached/1154063#1154063) if it is the case
- (ASP.NET) Check [this answer (by matrixugly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632427/how-to-edit-and-continue-in-asp-net-mvc-6/35073039#35073039) if it is the case
- (ASP.NET) Ensure you have *Edit and Continue* enabled on the *Web* tab (vs2010)
- (ASP.NET) Go to *Properties > Web > Servers*, and make sure that *Enable and continue* is checked under *Use Visual Studio Development Server*.
- (ASP.NET WebAPI) Make sure you've stopped in the Controller's method using a breakpoint, before trying to edit it.
- (ASP.NET MVC) Conditionally compile `app.UseResponseCompression()` to exclude from *Development* environment from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70023215/1190540).
- (ASP.NET Core 6) If used with RuntimeCompilation make sure the *nuget* packages is updated past 6.0.9 [Reference](https://github.com/nabinked/NToastNotify/pull/158), be aware that *Hot Reload* without *RuntimeCompilation* is new recommended [approach](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/23910), but a workaround if affects performance.
- (vs2017) Go to *Tools > Options > Debugging* and *uncheck* (deselect) 'Edit and Continue'. This is actually the opposite of the 'conventional' advice (see some other points in this post). It does not allow you to actually make changes in your *running* program (i.e. it does not hot-swap the code changes that you make) - it simply allows you to edit your code (i.e. it prevents that annoying message and "locking" your editor).
- Go to *Tools > Options > Debugging > General* and make sure *Require source files to exactly match the original version* is unchecked.
- Check Enable Windows debug heap allocator (Native only) [VS Community 2017]
- Are you using Microsoft Fakes? It inhibits Edit & Continue.
- Kill all the **.vshost.exe* instances by selecting *End Process Tree* in the *Task Manager*. VS will regenerate a correct instance.
- Remove all the breakpoints with *Debug->Delete All Breakpoints*
- *Enable and Continue* exists in both the *Tools > Options > Debugging* menu and also in the *Project Settings*. Be sure to check both places. edit & Continue is not supported with the extended Intellitrace setting.
- Be sure *Debug Info* in *Project Properties > Build > Advanced > Output > Debug Info* is set to *Full*
- Some plugin may be interfering. Check by disabling/uninstalling and then trying again the other solutions.
- If you're not paying enough attention, the error you get while trying to fix this may change to something else that is easier to diagnose. E.g. A method containing a lambda expression cannot support edit and continue.
- Make sure the System variable `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING` and/or `CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING` is not set to `1`. Some profilers set this when installing and leave it like that after uninstalling. Open a command prompt and type `set` to quickly check it your system is affected, if so remove the variable or set it to `0`:

  - In Windows 8 and above, search for *System* (Control Panel).
  - Click the *Advanced system settings* link.
  - Click *Environment Variables*.
  - Remove `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING` and/or `CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING`
- Be aware of [unsupported scenarios](https://web.archive.org/web/20171021002324/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7932e88z.aspx) (as reported in the question) and that [unsupported edits](https://web.archive.org/web/20171021003115/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/supported-code-changes-csharp).

---

** by 'you', I mean the visitor of the page who is hammering his head on a keyboard to find The solution.*

---

**Feel free to edit this answer to add your workaround if not listed here!**

Comment: For me this was the extra step that made it work: The script here by "matrixugly" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632427/how-to-edit-and-continue-in-asp-net-mvc-6

Comment: @AbhishekShrivastava i added it :)

Comment: It was the COR_ENABLE_PROFILING ... no idea why it was set. Thanks. Stopping hammering my head on the keyboard now.

Comment: I tried all but on worked. Then I realized I have to be in break mode (debug-> break all ) or at a break point. Please add this to your list. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7932e88z.aspx

Comment: I'm sure that "Uncheck the Optimize Code box for Debug Mode in Project Properties->Debug" works for me, amazing, i've almost lost any hope

Comment: Using Microsoft Fakes will also prevent Edit and Continue

Comment: @EricLabashosky I added that and hope more people contribute (I did flag this answer as a community wiki in order to encourage direct edits by other users).

Comment: Same here was the COR_ENABLE_PROFILING env var!

Comment: Works for me, thank you, the fourth line "Uncheck the Optimize Code checkbox for Debug Mode in Project Properties->Debug"

Comment: I ran through all the applicable steps above and no joy. Then restarted Visual Studio and hey presto, edit and continue is working. Not sure which of the steps fixed it but my COR_ENABLE_PROFILING was set to 1, so probably that.

Comment: In `Project > Build` for `Any CPU` targets, select `Prefer 32-bit`

Comment: The one thing that solved it for me isn't mentioned here: I had to *dis*able (uncheck) the “Enable Edit and Continue” option under Tools > Options > Debugging.

This is complete the opposite of what you would intuitively think, but this is what fixed it for me (i.e. prevented that annoying message and just let me edit my code).

Comment: @leo I encourage you to append that to the list

Comment: @beppe9000 I've added it as a solution to the question ... feel free to add it to your own answer (I can't edit yours)

Comment: @leo It's community wiki so you can edit freely. Doesn't the 'edit' button work for you? I see you have enough reputation to do that. Ps. I added a reference to your answer so there is less dispersion.

Comment: @beppe9000 Ah yes I see it now, I wasn't aware of that, thanks! I've added it.

Comment: @Niloofar Is there a way to make this happen automatically? Without it Edit and Continue is pretty much useless to me and I guess I'll just disable it (sad, because hot swapping is super useful in Rider).

Comment: ASP.NET - I had two issues, one was `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING` that was mentioned above as well as in the Project's **Properties** Folder `launchSettings.json` file, I had the following set in **environmentVariables** field `"ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"` which needed to be removed in for some profiles to get it to work.

Comment: It seems that there was one more modification I needed to change to IIS Express compilation working (though Kestral working fine without it) the environment variable `CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING` also needed to be set to **0**.

Be aware that after modifying you need to restart Visual Studio so that it can get the updated parameters.

Comment: It seems that removing `"ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"` had some unintended consequences to CSHTML compilation, now although Hot Reload works on changes it still compiled the server, which seemed to take more time for some of our developers, so for .net core 6, you could update the nuget **RuntimeCompilation** version to past **6.0.9** from [Github](https://github.com/nabinked/NToastNotify/pull/158). Also Hot Reload seems to be the recommended approach as referenced [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/23910)

Comment: Using RegEdit, set COR_ENABLE_PROFILING and CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING to 0 in the REGISTRY

Answer (score 23):

If you're debugging an ASP.NET application, go to properties > web > Servers, and make sure that "enable and continue" is checked under Use Visual Studio Development Server.

Comment: also need to press Pause while Debugging, then able to edit code

Comment: If i use local iis,  "enable and continue" is desable

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. I even re-installed VS 2008 but the problem did not go away. However, when I deleted all the break points then it started to work.

```
Debug->Delete All Breakpoints
```

I think it was happening because I had deleted an aspx page that had break points in its code, and then I created another page with the same name. This probably confused the VS 2008.

Answer (score 6):

"Edit and Continue", when enabled, will only allow you to edit code when it is in break-mode: e.g. by having the execution paused by an exception or by hitting a breakpoint.

This implies you *can't* edit the code when the execution isn't paused! When it comes to debugging (ASP.NET) web projects, this is very unintuitive, as you would often want to make changes between requests. At this time, the code your (probably) debugging isn't running, but it isn't paused either!
To solve this, you can click "Break all" (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>). Alternatively, set a breakpoint somewhere (e.g. in your `Page_Load` event), then reload the page so the execution pauses when it hits the breakpoint, and *now* you can edit code. Even code in `.cs` files.

Answer (score 5):

Couple of things to check

- Make sure your compile is set to Debug vs. Release
- Make sure you're not launching a mixed mode process
- If on a 64 bit machine Make sure to set the CPU target to x86 rather than AnyCPU

**EDIT**

I don't believe this should matter but make sure that the hosting process is enabled for the target platform.  Probably won't help.

If it repros for new projects then it might be something even more subtle.  I would try the following.

- Backup HKCU:\Software\Wow6432Node\VisualStudio\9.0 (maybe just rename it)
- Delete the same key
- Try the repro again

Comment: What is a mixed mode process? I even tried new winforms project.

Comment: I don't have the HKCU:\Software\Wow6432Node\ node

Comment: @nightcoder then try HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0

Answer (score 5):

None of the above solutions worked for me(running on a 64x machine).

Finally I clicked on `'advanced compiler settings'` and **UNCHECKED** `'enable optimizations`' and I can now step through code and edit while debugging.

Comment: This seems to be Visual Basic only: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07bysfz2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Works for me! VS2013, VB.Net, Frame 3.5

Comment: And where are these settings?

Answer (score 4):

For me, for a reason that I don't understand, the setting "Generate debug info" in the "Advanced Compiler Settings" was set to "pdb-only" instead of "Full".

By default, this parameter is always set to "Full" but a mysterious poltergeist has changed this parameter on last night. :)

P.S. I'm in Visual Basic .Net with Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 4):

If your concern is with an ASP.NET app, ensure you have edit and continue enabled on the web tab (vs2010). There was also a separate setting for ASP.NET debugging in earlier versions.

Regards,

Adam.

Answer (score 4):

I found that even though under project properties build & debug tab are set to Debug and all the other setting are correct I still get the message, however after digging some more
under the Build menu select Configurations Manager... and make sure Debug is selected in two places there as well. go figure...how many different places do they need to set debug?????? even though you set Project - Configuration to Debug then under Build - Manager it is not changed so you have change the same setting there as well Project Configuration - seems like a microsoft issue again.......

Answer (score 4):

This problem is due to Intellitrace setting

If Intellitrace is enabled make sure Intellitrace event only is checked

Otherwise this will not allow edit and continue..

If you will click on Intellitrace options you will see the warnings.

Comment: This is the problem, for me!

Comment: Searched all options in the Visual Studio Tools for "Intellitrace" and there is no such option in VS Community 2017.  A little more detail here helps.

Answer (score 4):

Following shooting helped me using VS2010:

go to Tools, Options, Debugging, General and make sure "Require source files to exactly match the original version" is unchecked.

Answer (score 3):

That happens when the debugger hasn't hit a breakpoint or you haven't hit Break All (pause).  It couldn't be that simple could it?

Comment: It happens when the debugger has hit a breakpoint and I'm trying to change something in the code.

Answer (score 3):

The error says a possible cause is: "the code being debugged was optimized at build or run time". Go to Project Properties->Debug and uncheck the Optimize Code box for Debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and the solution is easy. when you run your project please set in "Debug" mode not "Release". The another people solution can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

If I create a new project, edits while debugging do not work.  If I create a new website, edits while debugging work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this today - turns out that having Debug Info set to pdb-only (or none, I'd imagine) will prevent Edit and Continue from working.

Make sure your Debug Info is set to "full" first!

Project Properties > Build > Advanced > Output > Debug Info

Comment: Thanks a million. This method worked for me after nothing else suggested worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case just reseting to default debugger settings and setting IntelliTrace-> only intellytrace events helps

Answer (score 1):

Some things that seemed to help using VS2010:

- go to Tools, Options, Debugging, General and make sure "Require source files to exactly match the original version" is unchecked.
- multiple .vshost.exe instances can be left over from e.g. detaching the VS debugger from a stopped process.  This will interfere with breakpoints and compiles as well.  Use Task Manager, Processes tab to kill all instances of .vshost.exe by right-clicking each instance and selecting End Process Tree.  VS will create a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

I removed a dataset from my project because I didn't use it. After that I could modify the program when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I did all the changes mentioned in every other answer and none worked. What did I learn? *Enable and Continue* exists  in both the Tools >  Options > Debugging menu and also in the Project settings. After I checked both, Enable and Continue worked for me.

Comment: What project settings? You are too vague

Comment: @Adaptabi They meant if you go right-click your Project Name, click Properties, then (if it's a web project) click Web, there's a checkbox to make sure is checked for "Enable Edit and Continue" there.

Answer (score 1):

Seems illogic, but only way was disabling edit and continue from VS 2017 options... Then AspNet edit and continue began to work...

Comment: Exactly! It's counter-intuitive but what worked for me as well is to *dis*able "edit and continue". It won't "hot swap" the changes you make but at least you can simply edit your code, and then it will take effect upon restarting your app.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me was unchecking "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" under

> Tools -> Options -> Debugging

TBN: checking or unchecking "Require source file to exactly match the original version" seems not influences the E&C

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

Enable edit and Continue only work run IIS Express.
Don't work in Local ISS or External Host.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding my answer because the thing that solved it for me isn't clearly mentioned yet. Actually what helped me was this article:

http://www.rubencanton.com/blog/2012/02/how-to-fix-error-changes-are-not-allowed-while-code-is-running-in-net.html

and here is a short description of the solution:

1. Stop running your app.
2. Go to Tools > Options > Debugging > Edit and Continue
3. Disable “Enable Edit and Continue”

Note how counter-intuitive this is: I had to *dis*able (uncheck) "Enable Edit and Continue".

This will then allow you to change code in your editor without getting that message "Changes are not allowed while code is running".

Note however that the code changes you make will NOT be reflected in your running program - for that you need to stop and restart your program (off the top of my head I think that template/ASPX changes do get reflected, but not VB/C# changes, i.e. "code behind" code).

Comment: Only after reading your answer I realized that I was not looking for "Edit and Continue" but just "Edit while running" and I finally fixed my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**I install the stackify, when i enable this on icon tray, it stop my debugging with edit, so i found**

- Close the visual studio , in my case its vs2017
- Go to icon tray and right click on stackify icon and disable .NET Profiler
- Open Visual studio run application again in debug mode with debugger and it allow me edit while debugging

[image: see image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this annoying issue since I upgraded my VS 2019 to 16.4.3 and caused me a lot of headache.
Finally I solved the problem this way:
1. Stop Debugging
2. Select the solution from "Solution Explorer"
3. In the *Properties* window change the *"Active config"* Property From **"Release|Any CPU"** To **"Debug|Any CPU"**
4. In Debug > Options > General Check the **Edit and Continue** checkbox
That worked for me, and hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

embed interop types visual studio should be set to false

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen in a linked class file. The rest of the project allowed E&C, but I got the same error editing the linked file. Solution was to break linked file into it's own project and reference the project.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. My problem was that I could modify a file, but not another (both are in same project). Later I found that the file I couldn't modify was also part of another project. That another project (Unit Test) wasn't loaded, and *intelligent* VS debugger shows the error that assembly for this given file was not loaded, and changes aren't allowed. How weird!

Hence, I had to unload the unit-test project and continue the EnC debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I had a database project in the solution which stopped the webforms project from being editted.

I clicked "Unload" on the database project and everything now works sweetly.

Answer (score 0):

For VS2017 it can help to remove the .suo file in your solution, it worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem in Visual Studio 2005. My configuration is 64 bits. It was working fine on one of the VS solution but not the other. I noticed i **only** enabled "Enable edit and continue" for the project where i wanted to make changes in debug mode. This finally solved for me when I selected "Enable and Continue" for my **start up project** as well.

There was no configuration changes except the enable and continue needed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was happening after I had hit a breakpoint, had done some edits, then continued on stepping through the code, then finally hit F5 or "Continue" to get to the end and out of my code block.

After trying the "delete all breakpoints" option (Ctrl+Shift+PrtScn and OK on the prompt) and doing a Rebuild All, I still had an error in my Error Log with regard to my DLL for my project not loading... "Can't apply changes, x.DLL not loaded".  After restarting Visual Studio, all was fine again. For me, it turned out to be just this simple.

Other things here did not work for me, like "Require source files to exactly match the original version" was checked before and after things started working again just fine, and targeting "Any CPU" on my x64 machine is just fine, too (did not need to specify x86 or x64). I had "Enable Edit and Continue" enabled in my Tools > Options > Debugging and in my Project Properties > "Web" tab settings.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem in Rider.  I had opened the `.csproj` file directly instead of the `.sln` file.  The consequence is that the runtime configuration was not set to debug even though I clicked the debug button.  You'll notice it says `<No Configurations>` in the toolbar beside the debug button.

Answer (score 0):

VS2019 - ASP.NET Forms
In my case was Tools - Options - Windows Forms Designer - "Optimized Code Generation" <- to false

Answer (score 0):

Edit and Continue has not worked for these 2 particular projects since VS2013 so I have kept it around for those. A fresh attempt to get it working on VS2022 finally yielded a cause:

**On Error**

If you edit code within an On Error you get the "edits were made which cannot be compiled" error. Setting the Error list Show Options to Build + Intellisense you finally see the error "Updating a On Error statement around an active statement requires restarting the application" which is what is blocking continuing execution.

Sad, as I have intentionally kept this legacy error handling method for these two particular projects for a very specific reason and needing to go to structured error handling is a major productivity setback.

But now I need to use some more modern libraries which are no longer compatible with VS2013 so I am forced to move on.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for our case was disabling the Telerik JustMock Profiling. In Visual Studio 2022 the Hot Reload was only working when running without debugging (CTRL+F5).

If try to run in debug mode (F5) and edit a .cshtml file, the error message appears:

> Hot Reload can't automatically apply your changes. The app needs to be rebuilt to apply updates.

[image: Visual Studio - Hot reload can't apply changes error message]

Additionally, at the error tab on Visual Studio, there is another message:

> ENC2018   Changes made in project 'Project.Name' require restarting the application: Changes are not allowed when 'COR_ENABLE_PROFILING' environment variable is set.

[image: Visual Studio - Changes Required Restarting because of COR_ENABLE_PROFILING]

So the cause is the Registry (Regedit) key `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING` (Regedit) at
`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework`, and they are created if we activate the Progress/Telerik Just Mock Profiling extension, that we use in old projects in Visual Studio 2017.

[image: Disable Telerik JustMock extension on VisualStudio]

After turning it off, and restart the debugging app on VS2022, the debugging and hot reload can work together!