# Modifying the code while debugging in VS 2010 without rebuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

First of all I'm aware of [Modifying the code while debugging in VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138723/modifying-the-code-while-debugging-in-vs-2010) and other similar questions, but that don't help me.

I do know what is Edit&Continue, but I have to use x64 code, so E&C is not an option :c
+ E&C has soe limitations, like creating loops, etc.

What I want -- simply allow me to modify code, but perform debug like file wasn't changed.  Recompile only on next build (something like that what we have in C++)

For example I'd like to add some comments

Comment: Prior to E+C in Managed Code (which was introduced in VS2005) I used a 2nd instance of Visual Studio...

Comment: Close as Deferred (Moderator Decision: Sent to Engineering Team for consideration): [Edit and Continue is not supported when debugging a 64-bit application.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/736684/edit-and-continue-is-not-supported-when-debugging-a-64-bit-application).

Comment: Copy Paste the file into an empty text file to do annotations. Or use the debugger pins as simple annotations. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea46xwzd.aspx Last year Microsoft Research was working on Debugger Canvas, which allowed you to annotate your sources heavily. It seems to be in Research mode still, but you can download it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/debuggercanvas.aspx

Comment: Thanks, jessehouwing.
That's helps a bit. Can you pate that message as answer, so I'll mark it as bwest answer?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to modify the file the debugger is using for source view, since that would mess up symbolic information (line numbers).

Make a copy of the source code in another directory and edit the copy.  Use any version control system to sync changes between your two copies.

Comment: Hm, so it's seems that I'll need to open two copyes of visual studio?

It's not so convinient, plus it's quite hard to find requested line of code.



This worked well in C++ and nemerle.

Found one bug, made assumption, changed code, debugged next step.


It's quite lot of time to wait for solution to restart after each edit.

Comment: I do want to modify the file during the debugging. I am aware of that line numbers will be messed up.