# Edit and Continue VS2013 MVC project does't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I'm working in a company. After I made a update of my code, the Edit and Continue functionality provided by VS2013 seems not work any more. Every time i try changing the code using EnC the VS retrieve the following message:

> Changes are not allowed for this module as it was not build for
>   changes while debugging or the target .NET runtime doesn't support it

I check the EnC and the functionality is active.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with ASP.NET application than you can try this.

> go to properties > web > Servers, and make sure that "enable and
>   continue" is checked under Use Visual Studio Development Server.

Follow this [Debugging support for 64-bit Edit and Continue in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/26/debugging-support-for-64-bit-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx?PageIndex=3)

Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/1154063/2798643

Comment: I post my problem here because i already had access to the posts that you mention and none of them solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run your project with `IIS Express`, not `Local IIS`

Right click project (from solution explorer) > Properties > Web > Under Servers select IIS Express from combo box

Comment: Sorry men, but your solution didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

So, After I read the answer made by GovindaRajbhar, I check again the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/1154063/2798643 and I see the post made by 
*community wiki* after the correct solution, and the problem solved when I follow the point:

> Be sure Debug Info in Project Properties > Build > Advanced > Output >
>   Debug Info is set to Full

If anyone have some problem like mine, please follow the post mantion this answer and may solve your problems