# Can't edit and continue on MVC projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging

I've been able to edit and continue for more than a year. I don't know what unfortunate mistake I've made but I'm now not able of editing the code and continuing anymore, as when I try I get the "Changes are not allowed in the following cases".

I've been googling and changing settings for more than half a day straight now! x86, enable and disable, repair VS, 2015 and 2017 versions, check the project settings... As far as I can tell I've touched every single switch I can think of and I still can't edit and continue!

I've noticed though that I can edit and continue on a simple console program (Console.Write and .Read sort of thing) but not on a simple MVC project (the one that comes with the MVC scaffolding) so I'm now thinking is something to do with MVC.

Any thoughts? It's happening even with projects that I could edit and continue with in the past!

Comment: Have you tried turning it on and off again

Comment: on off, update, repair VS, reboot pc.....

Comment: I hope this link will provide you the guidance:https://stackoverflow.com/a/27672935/3397630

Comment: Thanks @KarthikElumalai, I thought I had gone though that whole post as well but it turned out it was the very last entry: the `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING` system environment variable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Karthik recommendation and https://stackoverflow.com/a/27672935/3397630 I just had to remove `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING` from the system and user variables!

There are a few more similar entries like `COR_PROFILER`, `CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING` and `CORECLR_PROFILER` but I left those there.

Comment: Glad to know that this issue has been resolved, you could mark it as the answer:)