# Hot reload is not available due to CS7096

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

If I hot reload after editing related to an interface in COM reference, CS7096 occurs and the hot reload fails.

```
// Start debugging this code.

var instance = temp as ComLib.ICom;
instance.Foo1();
```

```
// If I edit with this code and attempt to hot reload, CS7096 will occur and the hot reload will fail.

var instance = temp as ComLib.ICom;
instance.Foo2();
```

The only thing I found was "CS7096 - Cannot continue the edit inclusion a reference to an embedded type: 'ICom'."

Any solutions or related references?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27672935/3150445

Comment: Hot relead only works for fully managed code. It patches the IL in the runtime. It can't do that with COM objects.Hit reload is a  feature of the CLR and it does not exist for unmanaged code and COM as their "Runtimes" don't implement it. It's almost impossible to do that for unmanaged code anyway.