# asp.net debugging in iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-web-developer

i am using iis5.1 and visual web developer 2008. I used to open a website in vwd from local iis and debug the in coming requests,i was using .net 2.0 for all websites, but recently i installed .net 4.0 and modified a website configuration to use .net version 4, 
after that i am unable to start debugging, when i try to debug it shows an error message that reads

> Unable to start debugging on the Web server. the webserver did not
>   respond in a timely manner, this may be because another debugger is
>   already attached to the webserver

I have now uninstalled the .net 4 and changed all the websites in iis to use .net 2.0
but still i am unable to start debugging,
How can make it work again ?

Comment: Try running the `aspnet_regiis -i` commend?

Comment: i tried but still same error..

Comment: Have you changes the version to `4.0 ` in your `IIS`

Comment: Try doing an `iisreset /stop` & `iisreset /start` on the command prompt

Comment: Check here for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524/visual-studio-2008-debugger-already-attached-work-around

Answer (score -1):

Check if

```
<compilation debug=”true”/>
```

exists in web.config

Comment: Add this as comment this is not at all an answer